Overlay BEFORE-STRING face affected by comment face
I am propertizing the before-string of an overlay with
(overlay-put instruction
                          'before-string (propertize (concat label "\n") ; label = "REFERENCE"
                                                     'face (list :extend t
                                                                 :foreground label-color
                                                                 :background bg-color)))

and while it works most of the time, some outside faces seem to affect the before-string text. For example, below are two examples of the overlay: the first one is as I expect, while the second one has become bold due to being on the same line as the comment.

What can be done? Adding :bold nil to the propertization does not help.

There's no :bold face attribute, so that wouldn't have any effect. You're thinking of :weight 'bold.
:weight 'regular is what the default face uses, so I think you could use that -- or probably just :inherit 'default (or some other face you deem more appropriate) before setting your overrides.

Thank you, that worked.
